# org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property catch found for type

Tags: spring, spring-data

I have a issue with Spring Data repositories.

When I deploy, I get an exception and it's because Spring Data tries to derive dynamically the method, but can't find in the Entity the corresponding property.

How can I put a custom method in the Custom Repository without this issue?

These are the involved components:

1. `LocaleJpaImpl`: the Entity
2. `LocaleJpaRepositoryClient`: the business layer class
3. `interface LocaleJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<LocaleJpaImpl, Long>, LocaleJpaRepositoryCustom`
4. `interface LocaleJpaRepositoryCustom`
5. `LocaleJpaRepositoryImplemented implements LocaleJpaRepositoryCustom`

`LocaleJpaRepositoryCustom` has a method:

```
List<String> catchLanguagesCombinations() throws DAOSystemException;
```

(LanguagesCombinations isn't a property of LocaleJpaImpl. For that motive is in the Custom Repository).

This exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property languages found for type com.engine.i18n.domain.LocaleJpaImpl
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:74)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:326)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:352)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:306)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:244)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:73)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:180)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:260)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:240)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:68)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:57)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:90)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:162)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:68)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:280)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:148)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:125)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:41)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
... 33 more
```

---

This is the relevant code:

**1. LocaleJpaImpl:**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.AttributeOverride;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import com.jpa.BaseEntityJpaSupport;

@Entity
@Table(name = "LOCALE")
@XmlRootElement
@AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="LOCALE_ID"))

@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Locale.findAll", query = "FROM LocaleJpaImpl l"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Locale.findByLocaleId", query = "FROM LocaleJpaImpl l WHERE l.localeId = :localeId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Locale.findByLanguageCode", query = "FROM LocaleJpaImpl l WHERE l.languageCode = :languageCode")

public class LocaleJpaImpl extends BaseEntityJpaSupport implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //@Id
    //@Column(name = "LOCALE_ID")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer localeId;

    @Size(max = 2)
    @Column(name = "LANGUAGE_CODE")    
    private String languageCode;

    public LocaleJpaImpl(Integer localeId) { this.localeId = localeId; }    
    public int getLocaleId() { return localeId; }    
    public void setLocaleId(Integer localeId) { this.localeId = localeId; }      
    public String getLanguageCode() { return languageCode; }    
    public void setLanguageCode(String languageCode) { this.languageCode = languageCode; }
}
```

**3. interface LocaleJpaRepository**

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import com.engine.i18n.domain.LocaleJpaImpl;

public interface LocaleJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<LocaleJpaImpl, Long>, LocaleJpaRepositoryCustom {

    @Query("FROM LocaleJpaImpl L WHERE L.languageCode = :languageCode")
    List<LocaleJpaImpl> findLocaleByLanguageCode(@Param("languageCode") String languageCode);   

}
```

**4. interface LocaleJpaRepositoryCustom**

```
import java.util.List;
import com.util.DAOSystemException;

public interface LocaleJpaRepositoryCustom {

    List<String> catchLanguagesCombinations() throws DAOSystemException;
}
```

**5. LocaleJpaRepositoryImplemented**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import com.util.DAOSystemException;

public class LocaleJpaRepositoryImplemented implements LocaleJpaRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "contentEntityManagerFactory")
    private EntityManager em;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<String> catchLanguagesCombinations() throws DAOSystemException {

        return "result";
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Param("countryCode")` should be `@Param("languageCode")`

Comment: @Abhinav Sarkar: thank you! This is anothe bug. :)
Anyhow is not the cause of the exception. :(

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I had a issue like this and my mistake was the name of the custom repository class:

If the name of your jpa repository interface is `LocaleJpaRepository`, your new custom interface should be named `LocaleJpaRepositoryCustom`, but the class that makes the override in the method must be named `LocaleJpaRepositoryImpl`, as it follows:

```
public class LocalJpaRepositoryImpl implements LocalJpaRepositoryCustom{
@Override
   public void customMethod(){....}
}
```

Basically, the implementation class of your custom interface should start with the name of your repository interface (JPARepository) ending with 'Impl' keyword.

Comment: You were right: the class that implemented the RepositoryCustom interface had a wrong name LocaleJpaRepositoryImplemented and it should have been LocaleJpaRepositoryImpl following Spring-data conventions.
Modifying the Class name solved the issue.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Im doing the same thing, but I have an error. It is understanding the custom method im creating as a field of the Entity's repository.

Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property "METHODNAME" found for type "ENTITY"!

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Rename methods with `@Query` annotation. They shouldn't be like normal "findAll..." etc

Comment: Thanks @Koitoer you saved

Comment: It should be noted that, according to Spring documentation, your class name should be `LocalJpaRepositoryCustomImpl` not `LocalJpaRepositoryImpl`. But only by naming it LocalJpaRepositoryImpl makes it work, so that means [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior) is wrong on this. Quoted: `class CustomizedUserRepositoryImpl implements CustomizedUserRepository {`

Answer (score 0):

Custom Repository Implementation class name should be Interface name which is extending JPARepositry with Impl