# How to extract common methods from Spring repositories into default interface methods?

Tags: java, spring

There are a lot of places in the code like the following:

```
@Query("SELECT ...")
List<Foo> findAllRu();

@Query("SELECT ...")
List<Foo> findAllEn();

default List<Foo> findAll(){
    if (CurrentLocale.isRu()){
        return findAllRu();
    }
    else {
        return findAllEn();
    }
}
```

I'd like to extract `findAll` implementation into separate interface:

```
public interface FindAllI18nRepositoryProvider<T> {
    List<T> findAllRu();

    List<T> findAllEn();

    default List<T> findAllI18n() {
        return CurrentLocale.isRu() ? findAllRu() : findAllEn();
    }
}
```

And then extend repository interface with it:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
public interface FooRepository extends
        JpaRepository<Foo, Long>,
        FindAllI18nRepositoryProvider<Foo> {

    @Query("SELECT ...")
    List<Foo> findAllRu();

    @Query("SELECT ...")
    List<Foo> findAllEn();
}
```

However, Spring fails to start application with such interface methods:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fooRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAllRu found for type Foo!
...
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAllRu found for type Foo!
```

I've tried to add empty `@Query()` annotation, however, this does not help.

I've also tried to add `default` implementation for `findAllEn` method, however, in this case Spring ignores `@Query()` annotation in the repository interface.

So, my question is: is it possible to move stateless `findAll` method into separate interface? I don't want to write additional implementation class for repository interface or something like that.

Comment: I think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777785/org-springframework-data-mapping-propertyreferenceexception-no-property-catch-f

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Also, as far as I understand, this approach requires hand-written underlying class with repository implementation, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: I just tried your example in a spring-boot v1.3 application, (with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency) and it works just fine. Is the exception actually deriving from `FooRepository` and not some other interface?

Comment: @MartinHansen, yes, the exception message is `Error creating bean with name 'fooRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAllRu found for type Foo!`