# Spring Data JPA custom method causing PropertyReferenceException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have been trying to create a spring boot application. In my application I would like to add some custom methods to save the data instead of using the default save method.

My application entry point is something like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryImplementationPostfix = "CustomImpl")
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);         
    }

}
```

I have changed this line repositoryImplementationPostfix to even Impl but, it didn't work.

My CrudRepository

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface TaRepository extends CrudRepository<Ta, Integer> ,TestRepository{


    List<Ta> findByName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

**My Custom Repository:**

```
public interface TestRepository {
    public void myCustomMethod(TestDto dto);
}
```

**My Custom Repository Impl**

```
public class TestRepositoryCustomImpl implements TestRepository{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    @Override
    public void myCustomMethod(TestDto model){
}
```

**NOTE:**

If I change my CrudRepostory from the mentioned to this:

```
 @RepositoryRestResource
    public interface TaRepository extends CrudRepository<Ta, Integer> {


        List<Ta> findByName(@Param("name") String name);

    }
```

everything works fine. But not with the custom method implementation.

Comment: What it says? Any errors?

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property myCustomMethod found for type Ta!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777785/org-springframework-data-mapping-propertyreferenceexception-no-property-catch-f - this link says that you must change `TestRepositoryCustomImpl` to `TaRepositoryCustomImpl` and `TestRepository` to `TaRepositoryCustom`

Comment: Thanks it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Spring Data JPA `@Repository` or `@RepositoryRestResource` you never need to implement a Custom Interface. For any simple query you can create any kind of method, please follow the simple guide.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

For a complex query you can use JpaSpecificationExecutor.

[How can I create a Predicate from a HQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479366/how-can-i-create-a-predicate-from-a-hql-query/41479894#41479894)

Comment: This does not cover the case where you have to pre-fetch a 2nd level field of the root entity (ex: entity.field.subfield) which is lazy for other queries.