# Error creating bean with name | Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0

Tags: java, service, spring-data, repository, javabeans

I want to ask, whats wrong with this error?
I already check with other entity, they're doing good. But, can you guys help me for this trouble? Thankyouu

```
Error creating bean with name 'masterVersionServiceImpl' defined in file
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'masterVersionRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property name found for type MasterVersion!
```

Here my code

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    @Service
    public class MasterVersionServiceImpl extends CrudServiceImpl<MasterVersion, Long> implements MasterVersionService{

        @Autowired
        private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

        private MasterVersionRepository masterVersionRepo;

        @Autowired
        public MasterVersionServiceImpl(MasterVersionRepository jpaRepository) {
            super(jpaRepository);
            this.masterVersionRepo = jpaRepository;
        }

        public void setMasterVersionRepo(MasterVersionRepository masterVersionRepo) {
            this.masterVersionRepo = masterVersionRepo;
        } 

    //and other function


//the repository interface
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface MasterVersionRepository extends BaseRepository<MasterVersion, Long>{
    MasterVersion findById(Long id);
    MasterVersion findByName(String name);
}
```

Comment: have you googled the underlying error? looks a lot like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620903/spring-data-jpa-custom-method-causing-propertyreferenceexception

Comment: thankyou i already know the problem is on my repo.. thanks for sharing that link